# jQuery's Stylish-Select plugin doesn't work on elements created after page load

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been striving to use [`Stylish Select Box`](http://www.prismstudio.co.uk/2009/05/jquery-plugin-stylish-select-unobstrusive-select-box-replacement/) with elements created after page load without success. In order to understand the issue, you'll need to re-produce it first. I know the following might seem a bit annoying but please continue reading if if you have 5 minutes of spare time.

**Alternatively, you may obtain a completed example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XssbX/1/) to see the issue directly.**

First, you'll need a `<select>` element. Now bind [`jquery.stylish-select.js`](http://github.com/sko77sun/Stylish-Select/blob/master/jquery.stylish-select.js) to your `<select>` element using something like `$('select').sSelect();` after that the script hides the `<select>` element and creates a set of DIVs underneath it. Now your page should look like this :

```
<select style="display:none;">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<div class=newListSelected>
    <!-- Some other stuff(not important). -->
</div>
```

Now add another `<select>` element to the same page with something like `$('body').append('<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>')​` and use `$(.newListSelected).remove();` to delete the DIVs it created for the pervious ` option. Hope I'm sill clear enough.

After that you should have the following on the page :

```
<select style="display:none;">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Last, just call `$('select').sSelect();` once more. It should create DIVs under **both** of your `<select>` elements. Now here's the problem, The **first** select box represented by the DIVs doesn't behave properly.

**Alternatively, you may obtain a completed example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XssbX/1/) to see the issue directly.**

**Normally** when you choose an option from the select box represented by the DIVs, it should update the original `<select>` element's `selectedIndex` (DOM property) to the corresponding index of the chosen option(0 for first option, 1 for the second.. etc). But if you look closely you'll see its changing `selectedIndex` value to -1 for any option.

As I'm really new to Javascript I really have no idea why its behaving like this. What I could only probably think of would be due to the first element being binded to `$('select').sSelect;` twice, thus causing DOM problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your JS should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').sSelect();

    $('.add').click(function() {
        var newSelect =$('<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>').appendTo('body');
        $(newSelect).sSelect();
    });

    $('.bind').click(function() {
        $('.newListSelected').remove();
    });
});​
```

The trick is to use `appendTo` instead of `append`. That will return the newly created `select`, so you can use `.sSelect()` on it.

Comment: Do you mean only binding `.sSelect();` to the newly created `select` element?

Answer (score 1):

reset Stylish Select function

```
$('select').resetSS();
```

Answer (score 1):

use resetSS() function after manipulating your select options.

```
$('#sel2').sSelect();

function refresh_select(id){
    $.getJSON("/ajax.php?cat="+id, function(data){
        $("select#sel2").loadSelect(data);    
        $("select#sel2").resetSS();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you cant just simply delete the div. why can you not undo the sSelect thing? i'm sure there is a destroy option or remove or whatever, so remove the sSelect properly, then try again :)

Comment: Yes.. I was trying to find a way to revert sSelect, however I couldn't find anything inside jquery.stylish-select.js capable of doing that :(

Answer (score 0):

u have to call the sSelect function once more after creating the elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').sSelect();
});

$('.add').click(function() {
    $('body').append('<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>')
   $('select').sSelect();
});

$('.bind').click(function() {
    $('.newListSelected').remove();
    $('select').sSelect();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but that wouldn't work. If you call sSelect again without deleting the DIV elements first, you'll end with multiple DIVs for the first select box :(